# How to poll folder using relative path in camel test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, apache-camel

I am writing a camel route which polls the file from a particular folder and the name of the file has to be in a particular format because I am chechking the valid file name while polling the file in the route.
I am using an xml file and it has to validate against particular xsd in the route, then output the file to another folder after renaming.
For this how can I write the camel test to check the end to end flow within my test.
Facing issue in how to set the relative path for camel to pick. As in production I am not sure of the folder structure.
Pls Suggest.